# Check whether a module linked with Multithreaded dll (/MD) library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to check whether a c++ dll is linked with Multithreaded dll (/MD) library?
Is there any tools for checking that?

Comment: Did you try to export the list of imports from DependencyWalker? I _guess_ they're different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the imports with, say, Dumpbin.exe /imports.  If it was built with /MD then you'll see functions from msvcrXXX.dll being used.  Where XXX is the VS version number (90 = VS2008, 100 = VS2010, etc).